# Selenium / Java: "Actions" always releasing element on my cursor even with correct parameters

Tags: java, selenium, maven, drag-and-drop, action

I am trying to use the action class to simply drag and drop an element to a specific zone, but seems that with the solutions I tried, the element is always dropped where my real mouse cursor is like in this example:

[element is dropped even out of the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgUvl.png)

Here is my code:

```
     WebElement card = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='item']"));
     WebElement container = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[@class='text-center']"));

     Actions move = new Actions(driver);
     Action dragAndDrop = move.clickAndHold(card)
             .release(container)
             .build();
     dragAndDrop.perform();
```

I already checked if there were any frames on the page but no, I tried with providing exact position but the final issue remains the same, the dropped is done where my cursor is.

PS: Here is the portion of code where I found the drag and drop zone for more clarity:

[The object to drag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwPvE.png)

[The zone where I need to drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLwnm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that in using the robot class and with some adjustment I could solve this issue:

```
    WebElement container = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[@class='text- 
    center']"));
    Point coordinates2 = container.getLocation();
    WebElement card = 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='"+priority+"']"));
    Point coordinates = card.getLocation();
        
    Robot robot = new Robot();
        
    //drag 
    robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX() +100, coordinates.getY() + 150);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK); 
    Thread.sleep(100);
    //drop 
    robot.mouseMove(coordinates2.getX() + 400, coordinates2.getY() +300);
    Thread.sleep(100);
    robot.mouseMove(coordinates2.getX() + 401, coordinates2.getY() +301);
    Thread.sleep(100);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK); 
    Thread.sleep(100);
```

The "Thread sleep" are simply there to see the action and to help for the debug if needed. Then why I move two times at the beginning of the drop it's simply because I saw that if I don't do a second move before the release, the card will not appear and not drop correctly, it's like an extra action is needed to finalize the last action.